# How to syndicate partial-page content and maintain SEO?

Tags: seo, syndication

How do we share our partial HTML content without losing our SEO?

Since we're not sharing full HTML, we can't place "rel:canonical" in the header.

I've thought it'd be interesting to enclose our content in an article tag with a cite attribute to the original source.  Would Google respect that for SEO purposes?

```
<article cite="http://myoriginalsite.com/bestcontent">
This is syndicated content...</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what Canonical URLs are for. It's for the *content of the page*. Not the source code.

Comment: But I'm confused. How do I add the canonical tag if I don't control the header of the syndicated site?

Comment: You can't. But you can require that tag be present as part of the terms of service for syndicating the content.

Comment: Bummer.  Wish there was a way to embed that concept in the content snippet itself.  Makes more sense to syndicate content chunks than whole pages anyways.

Comment: Require your clients to use iframes instead?